# FieldValue is undefined

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using firestore in my react app. It is working without any problems when trying to get/create/update documents.
However I am unable to access FieldValue which I need to update an array using arrayUnion. My firebase version used is 6.6.2.

Specifically this is the code I'm trying to get to work:

```
const locations = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion('location 1')
firebase.firestore().collection('config').doc('groups').update({ locations })
```

`firebase.firestore()` is working in the exact same file but `firebase.firestore.FieldValue` is undefined.

Comment: How are you importing `firebase`?

Comment: @RicardoLopes I'm importing firebase like this: `import firebase from 'firebase'` and my firebase.js file looks like this:
`import * as firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/auth'
import 'firebase/firestore'
import 'firebase/storage'
import 'firebase/functions'

const { firebaseConfig } = require('./config.json')

const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

export default app`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution was to import FieldValue directly from the firebase package and NOT from the instantiated firebase app.

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'

const arrayToUpdate = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(value)
```

Comment: Hi, Could you tell em how you did that? I'm using ReactJS btw

Answer (score 1):

I believe since you are setting your `initializeApp` to `app`, you will instead want to use `app.firestore.FieldValue;`

Comment: Sorry didn't make it clear how I am importing firebase. I have a file called firebase.js and my default export in this file is called app, but since it's a default export the name shouldn't matter. I am then importing firebase like this: `import firebase from './firebase'`

Comment: Just wanted to comment that this worked to solve the issue for me. Thanks Dan.

Answer (score 0):

It does seem like an issue with the way you're importing firebase.

My app is initialized as:

```
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firestore);
```

I have an arrayUnion when using it like this:

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
const firestoreAdmin = admin;
const firestoreInstance = admin.firestore();

// Example: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion('entry-to-add'),
```

Comment: That is not what I am trying to do. I am trying to achieve the functionality described here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.FieldValue.html#arrayunion

Comment: Edited my answer to be more relevant

Comment: I am not using the admin sdk but the client side web sdk version... What irritates me the most is that in the same file using the exact same import I am able to use firestore as expected (eg. for getting a document from a collection).